# How to get Jquery UI Autocomplete working with Rails 4?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails 4.0.2 with jquery-rails (3.1.0) and jquery-ui-rails (4.1.1) gems. I'm trying to add [Autocomplete](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails) to the search form (using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) 3.1.0):

```
<%= form_tag products_path, method: :get, class: 'navbar-form navbar-left' do %>
   <div class='form-group'>
     <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], id: "navbar-search-input", class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Product name.....' %>
   </div>
   <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', id: 'navbar-search-btn', class: 'btn btn-default') do %>
     <i class='fa fa-search fa-fw'></i> Search
   <% end %>  
<% end %>
```

Here are my application JS and CSS files:

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.autocomplete
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

var ready;
ready = (function() {
  $('a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
  $("#navbar-search-input").autocomplete({
    source: '/products/autocomplete.json',
  });
});

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

**application.css.scss**

```
*= require bootstrap
*= font-kit-rails/ubuntu
*= require jquery.ui.autocomplete
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
```

Than my controller and route for the autocompletion:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  def autocomplete
    @products = Product.order(:name)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { 
        render json: @products.where("name ILIKE ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")
      }
    end
  end
```

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :products do
    collection do
      get 'autocomplete'
    end
  end
```

Now with all of this, my json file with all of my products at `/products/autocomplete.json` are there. The problem is if I type in anything, it gives me a blank dropdown and if I click on any area of the dropdown it will reset the search form field. Do you know how to get this to work?

**EDIT**

NOTE: I have a Product named **Rice**

```
Started GET "/products/autocomplete.json?term=ric" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-19 10:06:51 -0400
Processing by ProductsController#autocomplete as JSON
  Parameters: {"term"=>"ric"}
  Product Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE (name ILIKE '%%') ORDER BY "products"."name" ASC
Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 14.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms | Search: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Do you get any JS errors in your console?

Comment: @tirdadc There's no errors but my GET request isn't returning anything. Take a look at my edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  def autocomplete
    @products = Product.order(:name).where("name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:term]}%")
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { 
        render json: @products.map(&:name).to_json
      }
    end
  end
```

Comment: @NimishJain my limited understanding - when you type something into the autocomplete field it is passed to the controller as params[:term] which is then used to search the products and return that data to the callback function for processing.

Answer (score 3):

Judging by your note, it looks like you're not fetching the param correctly in your controller, so try:

`render json: @products.where("name ILIKE ?", "%#{params[:term]}%")`

Comment: Dang, I'm still getting the same results.