# Rails 4. Country validation in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I'm creating rails API and want to want to add validation for countries field which contains an ISO 3166-1 code on model level.

For example if use gem [carmen-rails](https://github.com/jim/carmen-rails), it provides only helper `country_select`. Is that way to use validation for accordance country for ISO 3166-1 code in the model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are just trying to validate that the country code entered is appropriate? this should work with `carmen`

```
validates :country, inclusion: { in: Carmen::Country.all.map(&:code) }
```

But if this is all you need seems like the [countries gem](https://github.com/hexorx/countries) might work well too. With `countries` you could do

```
validates :country, inclusion: { in: Country.all.map(&:pop) }
```

Or

```
validate :country_is_iso_compliant

def country_is_iso_compliant
  errors.add(:country, "must be 2 characters (ISO 3166-1).") unless Country[country]
end
```

**Update**

For Region and State you can validate all 3 at the same time like this.

```
validates :country, :region, :state, presence: true
validate :location


def location
  current_country = Country[country]
  if current_country
    #valid regions would be something Like "Europe" or "Americas" or "Africa"  etc.
    errors.add(:region, "incorrect region for country #{current_country.name}.") unless current_country.region == region
    #this will work for short codes like "CA" or "01" etc.
    #for named states use current_country.states.map{ |k,v| v["name"}.include?(state)
    #which would work for "California" Or "Lusaka"(it's in Zambia learn something new every day)
    errors.add(:state, "incorrect state for country #{current_country.name}.") unless current_country.states.keys.include?(state)
  else
    errors.add(:country, "must be a 2 character country representation (ISO 3166-1).")
  end
end
```

Although Region seems unnecessary as you could imply this from the country like

```
before_validation {|record| record.region = Country[country].region if Country[country]}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. [countries gem](https://github.com/hexorx/countries) works well.
How can I use this gem for state/region validation and accordance belonging region/state to the country?

Comment: @Derk153 provide a little more detail and I'll be glad to help. Are you looking to validate region state against a given country? Will this be the code e.g. CA for California, USA. Also are you capturing these as :country, :region,:state. Just for naming sake

Comment: I've created a new question http://stackoverflow.com/q/25065417/2115659  . Thanks a lot for help

Comment: @Derk153 answered in new question with modifications now that I understand

Answer (score 8):

Here is the newest syntax for validation with the `countries` gem:

```
validates :country, inclusion: { in: ISO3166::Country.all.map(&:alpha2) }
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a Fixture with the data provided by [Wikipedia on ISO-3166-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1) and validate the country based on that data.

Also you can create an auto-complete feature easing the input. You can look at the auto-complete [provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22507669/1006863) for guidance.