# Rails 4. Country and Region/State validation in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I have a table `User`

```
create_table :users  do |t|
   t.string :first_name
   t.string :last_name
   t.string :country
   t.string :region
   t.string :city

   t.timestamps
end
```

I need to validate country and region, also check does region belongs to country.
I use gem [countries](https://github.com/hexorx/countries) for country validation.

*#user.rb*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_inclusion_of :country, in:Country.all.map(&:pop), :message => "wrong country format"

end
```

How can I use validation for 'region' and check does region belongs to country

**UPDATE**

Using @engineersmnky's advice

*#user.rb*

```
  validates :country, :region, presence: true
  validate :location

  def location
      current_country = Country[country]
      if current_country
         errors.add(:region, "incorrect state for country #{current_country.name}.") unless current_country.map{ |k,v| v["name"]}.include?(region)
      else
         errors.add(:country, "must be a 2 character country representation (ISO 3166-1).")
      end
  end
```

Test this in console:

```
2.1.2 :001 > u = User.new(country:"US", region:"SomeState")
 => #<User id: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, country: "US", region: "SomeRegion", city: nil, address: nil, zip: nil, phone: nil, company: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
2.1.2 :002 > u.valid?
NoMethodError: undefined method `map' for #<Country:0x007fefb16dd140>
```

Where is mistake? or I understand something wrong :(

Comment: it should be `current_country.states.map{ |k,v| v["name"]}.include?(region)` you are missing the `states` `Hash`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moved from my previous post [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25057455/rails-4-country-validation-in-model/25061130?noredirect=1#comment38992918_25061130)

Although now I see by region you mean state

you could do this as well

```
#optionally in:lambda{|user| Country[user.country].states.map{ |k,v| v["name"]}}
#for named states see below for further explanation

validate_inclusion_of :region, in:lambda{ |user| Country[user.country].states.keys}, if: lambda{ |user| Country[user.country]}
```

For Country and Region/State you can validate both at the same time like this.

```
validates :country, :region, presence: true
validate :location_by_country


def location_by_country
  current_country = Country[country]
  if current_country
    #this will work for short codes like "CA" or "01" etc.
    #for named regions use:
    #   current_country.states.map{ |k,v| v["name"]}.include?(region)
    #which would work for "California" Or "Lusaka"(it's in Zambia learn something new every day)
    #for Either/Or use:
    #   current_country.states.map{|k,v| [k,v["name"]]}.flatten
    #this will match "California" OR "CA"

    errors.add(:region, "incorrect region for country #{current_country.name}.") unless current_country.states.keys.include?(region)
  else
    #optionally you could add an error here for :region as well 
    #since it can't find the country

    errors.add(:country, "has wrong country format")
  end
end
```

Comment: I've got error `undefined method `map' `. Please, look at question update

Comment: @Derk153 it should be `current_country.states.map{ |k,v| v["name"]}.include?(region)` you are missing the `states` `Hash`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Great answer, great solution. I love you dude, you are awesome!

Comment: @Derk153 No problem glad it worked. More importantly I hope you learned something along the way.

Comment: Region is the proper term. State is a type of region.

Comment: @Archonic thank you (I am aware) although that is a reference to a previous posted I answered for the same OP. That being said in the US regions and states are not the same a state is a subdivision of a division which is a subdivision of a region e.g. New York State is in Mid-Atlantic Division (2) of Northeast Region(1),  or California State is part of the Pacific Division(9) of the West Region(4) (According to the US Census Bureau) thus clarification of terminology is important